# c# string type behaves as value type in Object.MemberWiseClone()

Tags: c#, string, reference

Following the explanation and example of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0) (long code but very easy to follow, copy pasted directly from the documentation) I found the following:

```
using System;

public class IdInfo
{
    public int IdNumber;

    public IdInfo(int IdNumber)
    {
        this.IdNumber = IdNumber;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Person ShallowCopy()
    {
       return (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public Person DeepCopy()
    {
       Person other = (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
       return other;
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an instance of Person and assign values to its fields.
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Age = 42;
        p1.Name = "Sam";
        p1.IdInfo = new IdInfo(6565);

        // Perform a shallow copy of p1 and assign it to p2.
        Person p2 = p1.ShallowCopy();

        // Display values of p1, p2
        Console.WriteLine("Original values of p1 and p2:");
        Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
        DisplayValues(p1);
        Console.WriteLine("   p2 instance values:");
        DisplayValues(p2);

        // Change the value of p1 properties and display the values of p1 and p2.
        p1.Age = 32;
        p1.Name = "Frank";
        p1.IdInfo.IdNumber = 7878;
        Console.WriteLine("\nValues of p1 and p2 after changes to p1:");
        Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
        DisplayValues(p1);
        Console.WriteLine("   p2 instance values:");
        DisplayValues(p2);

        // Make a deep copy of p1 and assign it to p3.
        Person p3 = p1.DeepCopy();
        // Change the members of the p1 class to new values to show the deep copy.
        p1.Name = "George";
        p1.Age = 39;
        p1.IdInfo.IdNumber = 8641;
        Console.WriteLine("\nValues of p1 and p3 after changes to p1:");
        Console.WriteLine("   p1 instance values: ");
        DisplayValues(p1);
        Console.WriteLine("   p3 instance values:");
        DisplayValues(p3);
    }

    public static void DisplayValues(Person p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("      Name: {0:s}, Age: {1:d}", p.Name, p.Age);
        Console.WriteLine("      Value: {0:d}", p.IdInfo.IdNumber);
    }
}
```

In the second output I expected the `p2.Name` to be Frank as `string` is a reference type according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types), so should be affected by the name change in the original object.

```
// The example displays the following output:
//       Original values of p1 and p2:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42
//             Value: 6565
//          p2 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42
//             Value: 6565
//
//       Values of p1 and p2 after changes to p1:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: Frank, Age: 32
//             Value: 7878
//          p2 instance values:
//             Name: Sam, Age: 42   ---> EXPECTED FRANK HERE
//             Value: 7878
//
//       Values of p1 and p3 after changes to p1:
//          p1 instance values:
//             Name: George, Age: 39
//             Value: 8641
//          p3 instance values:
//             Name: Frank, Age: 32
//             Value: 7878
```

Actually both fields are dealt with in the DeepCopy method:

```
other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
```

Why is then the `IdInfo.Value` affected by the change of the original object and the `Name` its not if both are reference types?

Comment: Don't confuse *assignment* with *modification*. You're not modifying a string, you're assigning a new one.

Comment: thanks, that was exactly my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing here would depend on whether string is a reference vs value type. You create a clone of the `Person` - at that point, both `p1` and `p2` have the `.Name` pointing at the same `string` object. You then change the `.Name` on `p1`. Importantly: **this doesn't impact the string at all* - it simply changes `p1` to point at a **completely different string**. That is all that is happening here.

Since strings are outwardly immutable, you are almost always changing values to point at completely different strings; you (almost) never actually *change* a string that exists, so: whether it is reference type or value type is very rarely relevant, except in terms of understanding memory usage.

For that same reason: there's really no need to call `string.Copy`, and `string.Copy` *could* be implemented as just `return value;` (it isn't, though - I checked)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it matters becase by using ShallowCopy (what MemberWiseClone seems to do), the reference addresses are copied, so the copied reference addresses point to the same object. Due to this, changing one object should change the copies for ref types, shouldn't it?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay no, not in the least; again emphasis: **you are at no point changing the contents of any strings**. Strings are outwardly immutable.

Comment: so according to your explanation the `string` type, behaves as value type?

Comment: Re `string.Copy`, fun note from the docs: "Starting with .NET Core 3.0, this method is obsolete. However, we do not recommend its use in any .NET implementation. In particular, because of changes in string interning in .NET Core 3.0, in some cases the Copy method will not create a new string but will simply return a reference to an existing interned string."

Comment: @rustyBucketBay no, not that either; it is an *immutable* type; immutable types can be values or references

Comment: @MarcGravell I see your point now. Same as if  `p1.IdInfo = new IdInfo(7878);` is done, `p2` value is preserved (Value: 6565), because its reassigned, not modified. Thanks